# java colletion and arraylist

Tags: java, collections

How to restrict ArrayList to accept only int,float and double values?

```
ArrayList<Integer,Float,Double> al=new ArrayList<<Integer,Float,Double>();
al.add(5);
al.add(5.6);
```

Comment: You can't specify multiple types like this for an array list. Either choose one type, such as double, and cast everything to that type upon insertion, or use `Object` as the list type (which is not recommended).

Comment: Why are you trying to store a collection of multiple types? This dramatically increases the complexity of using such a list since all code which accesses its elements has to be able to determine what data type each element is.

Answer (score 4):

Create your custom class and use that in your `ArrayList`. Otherwise, by using for example `Number`, you'd end up with allowing more than those basic types.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an `ArrayList<Number>` however this would include the following types:

AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number` as Generc values:

```
ArrayList<Number> al=new ArrayList<Number>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this at runtime by extending ArrayList and overriding all methods that add data. Then you will be able to check the class of any object added to your ArrayList and decide whether to throw an Exception or just silently reject.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact requirements, but the simplest way would be to just use an `ArrayList<Double>`. If you want to add `3` you would have to write `add(3.0)` or `add((double) 3)`.

That wouldn't be exactly what you requested because the list wouldn't contain any `Integer` or `Float` objects.

We would need more information about your use case to be able to give the best answer.